# How to implement a multi step login in react or react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, router, react-navigation

I would like to implement a multi step login, similar to slack (it first asks the domain name, then the email, and later the password) in react and react-native.

I would like to know what are the best practices to do it?

Should I use a router/navigation solution like ReactNavigation https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation?

Comment: Why don't you chain the states responsible to show the field you want? Each time the user hits a "next", the state moves further. This way you wouldn't depend of the route which users could cheat on.

Answer (score 0):

That's one way to do it, sure. The way I would do it is a single component:

```
class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { stage: 0 };
    }

    onDomainSubmit(data) {
        this.props.getDomain(data.domain).then((domain) => {
            this.setState({ domain, stage: 1 });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { stage, domain } = this.state;

        if (stage === 0) {
            return <GetDomainForm onSubmit={ this.onDomainSubmit }... />;
        } else if (stage === 1) {
            return <LoginToDomainForm domain={ domain }... />;
        }
    }
}
```

`getDomain` is an action creator which has been injected into the component via `react-redux`'s `connect` - although that's not necessary.

there's less headache that way, and everything you need is contained within one component.

Comment: This has a problem that for each stage you'd have to change the if's.

Comment: I've answered it based on you're answer which I think is not effective because you lock the developer to the if/else and [that's not a good idea](http://cirillocompany.de/pages/anti-if-campaign)

Comment: You're right on that, though what I meant was that using if/else to lock up the developer is a bad idea. As any other tool, if/else should be used to the right problem, and I don't think it is the case because of the fore mentioned issues it raises.

Comment: "if/else to lock up the developer is a bad idea" there's only two, maybe three components... If there were 10+, your solution would be objectively better, but there's absolutely nothing wrong with a smaller if/else chain. It's needlessly complicating this question.

Comment: @MVCDS "lock up the developer" is a phrase without meaning. Please don't post answers which involve only trivial stylistic changes to other answers.

Comment: @meagar let me rephrase it. Imagine you have 5 stages, POs are still deciding how they look like and the order they should appear, it means that devs would have to move, add or remove much more code than if the stages were placed on an array, in this sense the dev is kind of a hostage to this login's changes

Comment: @TylerSebastian sibelius asked about multi-steps login, and gave slack as example which has two steps, but I couldn't find how many steps he is planning to have - assume is equal to slack because it is the example is not a good idea IMO, that's why I prefere the other style

Comment: @meagar is was neither trivial nor stylistic, it changes the understanding and solution of the problem by not having the dev to change, add or remove 'ifs', allowing it to rearange, add and remove stages more easily

Answer (score 0):

you can use SwitchNavigator.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator, SwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


import AuthLoadingScreen from '../views/users/auth';
import LoginScreen from '../views/users/login';
import RegisterScreen from '../views/users/register';
import ResetPasswordScreen from '../views/users/resetPassword';
import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';

export const AuthStack = StackNavigator({
  Auth:         { screen: AuthLoadingScreen, navigationOptions: { header: null } }, 
  Login:        { screen: LoginScreen, navigationOptions: { header: null } }, 
  Register:     { screen: RegisterScreen, navigationOptions: { header: null } },
  ResetPassword:{ screen: ResetPasswordScreen, navigationOptions: { header: null } }  
},{
  initialRouteName: "Auth"
});

export const AppStack = TabNavigator(
  { screen: MainTabNavigator, },
  { navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#f4511e', },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: 'bold', },
  },
}
);


  export const createRootNavigator = () => {
    return SwitchNavigator(
      {
        SignedIn:  { screen: AuthStack },
        SignedOut: { screen: AppStack }
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: "SignedIn"
      }
    );
  };
```